# Getting a problem in django url when I am at url ...abc/pqr and I click on xyz than It is not getting to the ...xyz but ...abc/xyz

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am getting a problem in my project of college management system. I have tried to add an assignment submission functionality in my project. In which when a student clicks on an assignment created by teacher, it will lead him to a page which is : either submission page of assignment or if he had already submitted that assignment then update or only showing information about that.

**urls.py file of project**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('cmsapp.urls')),
    
    ]
    urlpatterns+= static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**urls.py for cmsapp.**

```
    urlpatterns = [...
    path('studentattendancereport', studentviews.student_attendance_report, name='studentattendancereport'),
    path('fetchstudentattendance', studentviews.fetch_student_attendance, name='fetchstudentattendance'),
    path('applyforleavestudent', studentviews.applyforleave, name='applyforleavestudent'),
    path('marksreportstudent', studentviews.marksreportstudent, name='marksreportstudent'),
    path('assignment', studentviews.assignments, name='assignment'),
    path('assignmentupload/<int:id>', studentviews.assignment_upload, name='assignmentupload'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def assignments(request):
    subject = Subject.objects.filter(course=Student.objects.get(admin=request.user.id).course)
    assignments = []
    for s in subject:
        for a in Assignment.objects.filter(subject_id=s.id):
            assignments.append(a)
    context = {'assignments': assignments}
    return render(request, 'cmsapp/student/assignments.html', context)
    
def assignment_upload(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student_id = Student.objects.get(admin=request.user.id)
        assignment = Assignment.objects.get(id=id)
        assignment_file = request.FILES['assignment']
        try:
            Student_Assignment.objects.create(assignment_id=assignment, student_id=student_id, document=assignment_file)
            messages.success(request, 'Assignment is submited successfully.')
            return redirect('assignment')
        except:
            messages.error(request, 'There is some problem, Please try again later.')
            return redirect('assignment')
    else:
        assignment = Assignment.objects.get(id=id)
        student_id = Student.objects.get(admin=request.user.id)
        assignment_report = Student_Assignment.objects.filter(assignment_id=assignment.id, student_id=student_id).first()
        if assignment_report:    
            context = {'assignment':assignment, 'assignment_report':assignment_report, 'student_id':student_id}
            return render(request, 'cmsapp/student/assignment_report.html', context)
        else:
            context = {'assignment':assignment, 'assignment_report':assignment_report, 'student_id':student_id}
            return render(request, 'cmsapp/student/assignment_upload.html', context)
```

**assignment.html**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="heading">Assignments
        </h3>
         <table class="table table-hover table-bordered mt-4">
             <tr class="bg-dark text-white"><th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Subject</th><th>Session</th><th>Created_at</th><th>Updated_at</th></tr>
             {% for a in assignments %}
             <tr>
                 <td><a href="{% url 'assignmentupload' a.id %}">{{a.id}}</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{% url 'assignmentupload' a.id %}">{{a.title}}</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{% url 'assignmentupload' a.id %}">{{a.description}}</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{% url 'assignmentupload' a.id %}">{{a.subject_id}}</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{% url 'assignmentupload' a.id %}">{{a.session_id}}</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{% url 'assignmentupload' a.id %}">{{a.created_at}}</a></td>
                 <td><a href="{% url 'assignmentupload' a.id %}"></a></td>
              </tr>
                {% endfor %}
         </table>
    </div>
```

**assignment_upload.html**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="heading">Assignment</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-capitalize">
            <tr><th>Assignment Id</th><td>{{assignment.id}}</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Title</th><td>{{assignment.title}}</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Description</th><td>{{assignment.description}}</td></tr>
            <form action="{% url 'assignmentupload' assignment.id %}" method="POST" class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="file" placeholder="assignment" name="assignment" class="form-control mt-4">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success form-control mt-2">Submit</button>
            </form>
         
    </div>
```

**assignment_report.html**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h3 class="heading">Assignment</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-capitalize">
            <tr><th>Assignment Id</th><td>{{assignment.id}}</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Title</th><td>{{assignment.title}}</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Description</th><td>{{assignment.description}}</td></tr>
            <tr> <th>Your Assignment ID</th> <td>{{assignment_report.id}}</td></tr>
            <tr> <th>Student ID</th> <td>{{assignment_report.student_id.id}}</td></tr>
            <tr> <th>Document</th> <td>{{assignment_report.document}}</td></tr>
            <tr> <th>Update</th> <td><form action="" method="POST" class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="file" placeholder="assignment" name="assignment" class="form-control mt-1" style="width: 40%; display: inline;" accept=".pdf">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm mt-2" style="display: inline; float: right; width: 20%;">Update</button>
            </form></td></tr>
        </table>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" href="{{assignment_report.document.url}}" open>Open</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" href="{{assignment_report.document.url}}" download>Download</a>
            <p style="font-size: 12px; color: gray;">To Open or Download Assignment file click on buttons above.</p>
         
    </div>
```

**base.html**

```
    <div style="height: 120%; min-height: 96vh; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-content: stretch;">
        <div class="container d-flex align-content-stretch flex-wrap float-left"
            style="width: 15%;float: left; background-color: black;">
            <nav class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                {% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link nav-fill {% if url_name == 'studentdashboard'%}active{% endif %}"
                    href="{% url 'studentdashboard' %}">Dashboard</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link subject {% if url_name == 'studentattendancereport'%}active{% endif %}"
                    href="#">Subjects</a>
                {% for s in subject %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link d-none subject-token border border-dark {% if url_name == 'studentattendancereport'%}active{% endif %}"
                    href="#">{{s}}</a>
                {% endfor %}
                <a class=" nav-item nav-link {% if url_name == 'studentattendanceview'%}active{% endif %}"
                    href="studentattendancereport">Attendance</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link {% if url_name == 'studentattendanceview'%}active{% endif %}"
                    href="marksreportstudent">Marks</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link {% if url_name == 'assignment' or url_name == 'assignmentupload' %}active{% endif %}"
                    href="assignment">Assignment</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link {% if url_name == 'applyforleave'%}active{% endif %}"
                    href="applyforleavestudent">Leave</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Feedback</a>
                {% endwith %}
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>

            </nav>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: white; width: 85%; float: right; height: 100%;">
            {% if messages %}
            <div class="messages container mt-2">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <div{% if message.tags %}
                    class="alert text-capitalize alert-{% if message.tags == 'error' %}danger{% else %}success{%endif%}"
                    {% endif %}>{{ message }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div style="width: 100%;margin-top: 5px;">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I have similar type of url for update student details where it not throwing such wrong url.

Comment: Please share the main urls file and which view/template has the problem?

Comment: I dont know where the problem is arising, but the problem is something like that, when I come in assignment_upload view and than the url in browser url becomes preurl/assignment_upload/id_of_assignment and after that when i click on some other link than it not goes to that link but in browser url shows preurl/assignment_upload/link_that_i_click_on however it should be preurl/link_that_i_click_on,   i have added the projects main urls.py above the app urls.py file

Comment: I'm not getting you,  you be precise so any of us can help.

Comment: Sir, I think problem is in assignment_upload view, and template assignment_report.html and assignment_upload.html, Sorry sir for that I am unable to tell exact situation, I am new so I dont know exact terminology.

Comment: when I am in assignment_upload view than the browser show url like http://127.0.0.1:8000/assignmentupload/1       1 is here assignment id , and when i click from here on link applyforleavestudent which is in base.html which is extended with assignment_report.html than it goest to http://127.0.0.1:8000/assignmentupload/applyforleavestudent    but it should get to   url   http://127.0.0.1:8000/applyforleavestudent

Comment: Which link are you clicking

Comment: <a class="nav-item nav-link {% if url_name == 'applyforleave'%}active{% endif %}"
                    href="applyforleavestudent">Leave</a>  this is the link and it is in the base.html which is extended in assignment_report.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `base.html`

When you set `href` for your `<a>` tags, make sure it is

```
href="{% url 'some-url-name' %}"
```

For example, what you have written

```
href="studentattendancereport"
```

this will just append that to your current url

You have to make that correct for

```
href="studentattendancereport" ---> href="{% url 'studentattendancereport' %}"

href="marksreportstudent" ---> href="{% url 'marksreportstudent' %}"

href="assignment" ---> href="{% url 'assignment' %}"

href="applyforleavestudent" ---> href="{% url 'applyforleavestudent' %}"
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to learn more about `django's url template tag`

Comment: thank you so much Sir. now it is working.